# which kernel: I am using 12.04 Ubuntu media version

Tags: 12.04, kernel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I determine the version of the running kernel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2884/how-can-i-determine-the-version-of-the-running-kernel)

how can I find out what kernel is in my machine. I am using 12.04 Ubuntu media version